# That TextBox should retain the same value even after closing the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three text boxes for input values, I wish to retain the values even after closing the form. Is it possible?

Comment: You have to store them in settings or else make use of some other storage options like database or file and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use User Settings. They're different from Application Settings because they can be read and write between different sessions of the same applications.

You can create a new setting at design time:

1. Solution Explorer > Properties
2. Double-click on the .settings file (this creates a new set in the default settings).
3. Set name and type of your settings, plus an initial value in the value form. The scope is "user";

At this point, assuming you created a `mySetting1` setting of `int` type, you load this value in the textbox

```
int myValue = myNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.mySetting1;
myTextBox1.Text = myValue.ToString();
```

When closing the form, be sure to save the new value (I assume you checked for integrity):

```
int myvalue = int.Parse(myTextBox1.Text);
myNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.mySetting1 = myValue;
myNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

More of this on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Bye!
Davide.

Comment: myNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.mySetting1.Save(); the save function showa error: the no extension method of Save()

Comment: @MThiyanithi sorry I edited my answer: myNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Comment: Ex: Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); not added mySetting1 right. thanking you Mr.Davide